# Why sin(x) is in O(x) but not in O(x^2)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

I have been taught orders of growth and have just recently been introduced to the concept of big O, I'm sorry If the question is a bit naive.

It was said $sin(x)$ is in $O(x)$ but not in $O(x^2)$ when x approaches $0$ but the Taylor expansion of $sin(x)$ is of much higher order than $x^2$ so I would think it would approach zero slower than $x^2$ approaches zero so it would be in $O(x^2)$

Where have I gone wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: What is the definition you know for $O(\cdot)$? $f(x) = O(g(x))$ means, ignoring technical details and constants, that "$f(x) \leq g(x)$". You said yourself that $\sin x$ approaches zero *much slower* than $x^2$...

Answer (score 4):

If $\sin $ was $O(x^2)$ then for some $K$ we would have $| \sin x| \le K|x|^2$ for small $x$. This would imply that $\sin'(0) = 0$ which contradicts $\sin'(0)= \cos(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that what you miss is that when $x$ approaches $0$, $O(x^2)$ is *smaller* than $O(x)$.

[image]

Comment: Plot labels would greatly help ($x^2$, $x$, $\sin x$).

Comment: @ClementC.: I leave placing them as an exercise.

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Comment: No idea. Not by me, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the different uses of "is of order": The "order" of the Taylor expansion says how many terms you take into account. The big-O notation $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(x)$, "f is of order x", is a statement about the limiting behaviour of f in a specific limit, here $x \rightarrow 0$. I.e. that in this limit
$\frac{f(x)}{x}$
is finite. Think about the limit $x \rightarrow 0$ of
$$\frac{x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 + ...}{x}$$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)= \frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ and $x_n=\frac{(2n+1) \pi}{2}$ for $n \ge 1.$ Then

$$1/x_n \to 0$$

but

$$|f(1/x_n)| \to \infty$$

as $ n \to \infty.$